# Fetch api data on client side with nuxt3 when user clicks button and display in template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I'm pretty new to vuejs and nuxt and need a little help.

I am trying to fetch some sub menu items from an api when the "▾" is clicked on the ui. I want to show a pending icon while the data loads. The data only needs to be fetched once.

How can I use {data, pending, error} values from nuxt's useFetch in the template if they are not created until the method is called?

I get reference errors using the below example. I have also tried setting some empty refs as placeholders and updating them once data has been returned but this didn't work.

```
<template>
    <NuxtLink :to="url">
        {{ label }}
        <span @click.prevent="getChildren()">▾</span>
    </NuxtLink>

    <!-- Submenu -->
    <div v-if="isExpanded" @click="isExpanded = !isExpanded">
        <div>{{ subMenuItems }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

    const props = defineProps({
        label: String,
        url: String,
    });

    // Expand sub items
    const isExpanded = ref(false);
    const handleExpand = () => {
        isExpanded.value = !isExpanded.value;
    };

    // Fetch sub items.
    const getChildren = () => {
        handleExpand();
        const { data: subMenuItems } = useLazyFetch(() => '/api/items', {
            server: false,
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Because the useLazyFetch hook from nuxt-use-fetch returns the data value asynchronously, it won't be accessible in the same scope as your getChildren function. This is the problem you're running into.

Use Vue's watchEffect function to monitor changes in the data value and update a subMenuItems ref when they occur to resolve this problem. A pending ref can also be used to display a loading spinner while the data is being fetched.